# How to write a REST web service using Apache jclouds

Tags: rest, openstack, jclouds

I want to write a REST web service using Apache jclouds .
This web service will list the number of virtual machine running on openstack.
Can you please tell me from where to start with the REST web service development using Apache jclouds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't actually use jclouds to **write** a web service. It's probably best to use a JAX-RS based framework like Jersey or RESTEasy to write a REST web service.

jclouds is effectively for **reading** cloud web services. To list the number of virtual machines running on OpenStack, have a look at the [jclouds Nova Example](http://jclouds.apache.org/guides/openstack/#nova) that lists servers.

Comment: Hi Everett, Does that mean jclouds is REST client library ?

Comment: It's a cloud client library. It speaks REST or weird XML or whatever the cloud service requires.